# Why do shorthand lambda expressions only work in some cases?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Eg, these two statements both check each character of a string to see if it is a digit

```
 “abc3def".Any(c => char.IsDigit(c));
 "abc3def".Any(char.IsDigit);
```

How does the second statement work, and where else can I use shorthand expressions like this. It doesn’t seem to work in all cases.
 I’ve not come across any other examples?

Comment: What's an example that doesn't work? And I don't know C#, but the second doesn't look like a "shorthand lambda", it looks like you're just referencing the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In c#, the compiler can implicitly convert a method group (e.g. `char.IsDigit`) to a delegate if their signatures match. This is called a "method group conversion" (you can google it).

In this case `string.Any` has an overload that accepts a `Func<char, bool>` (a delegate that takes in a `char` and returns a `bool`) which `char.IsDigit` matches that signature (it takes a `char` and returns a `bool`). Therefore, the compiler is able to implicitly convert `char.IsDigit` to `Func<char, bool>`.